# Comparing string against numeric field returning unexpected results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Given the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Add a couple of rows:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`name`) VALUES (NULL , 'Bob'),(NULL , 'Larry'),(NULL , 'Steve');
```

Why, OH WHY! does this query return results:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = "2this-is-not a numeric value"
```

Result:

```
query returned 1 row(s) in 0.0003 sec
id  name
-----------------
2   Larry
```

The string used in the where clause is clearly being converted to a numeric value -- who said to do that?! I cannot find any documentation that suggests mysql or PHP would presume to auto-cast my string literal.

This only works if the numeric character is the first one in the string, `"this 2 is not numeric"` would not return results. `"12 2"` would become `12`, `"1 2"` (one-space-two) becomes `1`.

**Any articles or documentation explaining this behavior would be appreciated.**

Comment: doens't mysql use ' instead of " to denote string? it might just be looking at the numeric value try to cast it to numerber implicitly and then truncate the non-numeric values.   So... Why oh why! :D are you using quotes for a Numeric field forcing it to do an implicit conversion?  needless to say I believe it odd behavior as well.

Comment: Either. I always use single quotes for code, so I always send double quotes to sql

Comment: I wonder what result you'd get if you cast your string to bigint implicitly in a select.  If you get 2... then it's the implicit conversion and my o my is that ODD behavior.

Comment: Again though... Why are you using any quotes at all?

Comment: In the actual code, the query is assembled by a function that wraps all the column names in backticks (`) and wraps all the values in quotes. Clearly, this function cannot continue to be used -- auto-casting is frustrating.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's in the MySQL documentation here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT( "2this-is-not a numeric value", UNSIGNED )` returns `2`. Maybe you could add this to your answer.

Comment: DO NOT LIKE. I want 0 results -- no row has an id of "2yourmom". When I say `WHERE id = "2yourmom"`, I mean literally where the id is equal to that value. Auto-cast sucks, whereever it happens, in any language. Anyway... thanks for the link :D

Comment: +1 this Nails the reason.  Implicit converts in mysql WILL drop the non-numeric values after an int and then do the implicit conversion.  Scary as hell to me but it's in the docs

Comment: Great, now I need a PHP/JS-esq `===` operator, hehe